# How can i load and display database data in my view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

On my admin page, I want to display all the rows of data in 2 tables. One is users and the other is final products. 
Here is my view code:

```
<h3> Admin Page </h3> <?php 
echo "</br>";?>
<h4>Users</h4>
<?php 

print "<table id='t05'>";
print "<th>ID</th>";
print "<th>Username</ th>";
print "<th>Password</ th>";
print "<th>Email</ th>";

foreach ($data->result() as $row)
{
echo "<tr>"; 

echo "<td>". $row->id ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>". $row->username ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>". $row->password ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>". $row->email ."</td>"; 
echo "<td><a href=amend.php?id2=". $row ->id .">Amend</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=delete.php?id2=".$row->id .">Delete</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=add.php>Add</a></td>";
echo "</tr>"; 

}

print "</table>";
echo "</br>";
?>
</body>
```

My controller code is:

```
public function admin()
{
$this->load->view('head');
$this->load->model('admin_model');
$data['users'] = $this->admin_model->show_data(); 
$this->load->view('admin', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

My model code:

```
<?php
class Admin_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function show_data()
{
$query = $this->db->get('users');
return $query->row_array();
}
}
```

I am getting the error : Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on null in /customers/9/1/9/stecarterisd.co.uk/httpd.www/MVC/application/views/admin.php on line 13

Also, 'Message: Undefined variable: data"???

Comment: I would recommend against doing all of that logic in the template.

Comment: What do you mean template?

Comment: The template meaning the page HTML. CodeIgniter is not too strict about MVC so you're able to do a lot in the template, but it is a lot easier to maintain projects when you have the controller loading in the data to the template, and the data being collected and maintained in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller needs to extract the data from your model (optionally modifying it) and pass it into the view.
That is a good way to separate your model from the view.

The way in CodeIgniter to pass data to the view is by passing data into the $data array like so:

```
$data['users'] = $this->UserModel->getUsers();
$this->load->view('admin', $data);
```

Now $data['users'] will be accessible in your view as a variable "$users"
and you can loop through this array in your view like you do now.

Comment: I have changed my question :) Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

in you model controller you are using

```
return $data->row_array()
```

just replace it with

```
return $data->resullt()
```

or

```
return $data->result_array()
```

than in foreach loop use

```
 foreach($users as $row)
```

not

```
foreach($data->result() as $row)
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

All what you done is right,replace the following code in your model.

```
return $query->result();
```

And now replace the $data to $users in your view like this.

```
foreach ($users as $row)
{
 //your code here.
}
```